# Why is the solution to $s'' - w^2s = 0$ found to be $s = Ae^{wt} + Be^{-wt}$ (where $A$, $B$, and $w$ are constants, and $s$ is a function of $t$)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I solve the differential equation, I get a different solution.

With
$$
s'' - w^2s = 0
$$
the characteristic equation would be
$$
\lambda^2 - w^2 \lambda = 0
$$
the roots of this being
\begin{align}
\lambda &= \frac{-(-w^2) \pm \sqrt{(-w^2)^2 - 4(1)(0)}}{2(1)}\\
&= \frac{w^2 \pm w^2}{2}
\end{align}
therefore
$$
\lambda = w^2, 0
$$
since the roots are real, and distinct, this means that the general solution would be
$$
s = Ae^{w^2 t} + Be^{(0)t}
$$
and so
$$
s = Ae^{w^2 t} + B
$$
Where am I making a mistake in my solution?

Comment: In the title, you have $s''w^2s=0$. In the body, you have $s-w^2s=0$. Your characteristic function doesn't correspond to either of these. Please edit your question, carefully.

Comment: @GerryMyerson fixed. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not fixed. You still have three different things.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ah sorry, didn't notice the title.

Comment: OK, now it's down to two different things. How did you get that "characteristic equation"?

Comment: Oh I see my mistake. The characteristic equation should be $\lambda^2 - w^2 = 0$. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a side note, using the quadratic formula is overkill, factoring gives the solution quite trivially without all the computations.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was my characteristic equation. It should be
$$
\lambda^2 - w^2 = 0
$$
so
$$
\lambda^2 = w^2
$$
and so
$$
\lambda = \pm w
$$
therefore
$$
s = Ae^{wt} + Be^{-wt}
$$